# How to keep fixed aspect ratio for a button in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a set of buttons in a horizontal layout. I have set an image drawable as the background for each of these buttons. But when I make the linear layout to span the width of the screen, the buttons lose their aspect ratio. I want to keep its aspect ratio as is. I mean I have to keep it square shaped through out the application what ever the screen resolution is. How can I do this. Any suggestions is appreciated.

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/answer_bg"
        android:padding="10dip" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/img_background"
                android:height="50dip"
                android:text="@string/x"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/img_background"
                android:height="50dip"
                android:text="@string/x"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/img_background"
                android:height="50dip"
                android:text="@string/x"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you try removing the attribute android:height="50dip" first of all?

Comment: Yeah, I tried removing it. But didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm giving an improvement to your XML. I have not tested it, but it should work. The suggested changes are, instead of setting the image as background, set it as src for ImageButtons. Also, if you insists the Button, you can wrap each of the buttons with another layout and set its gravity property to "center". Take a look at the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/answer_bg"
        android:padding="10dip" >
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/img_background"
                android:height="50dip"
                android:text="@string/x"
                android:textStyle="bold" /></LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/img_background"
                android:height="50dip"
                android:text="@string/x"
                android:textStyle="bold" /></LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/img_background"
                android:height="50dip"
                android:text="@string/x"
                android:textStyle="bold" /></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Feel free to ask if it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok. It worked. but there was some problems. When I removed the 50dip parameter, it is working fine. Can you tell me what android:layout_weight parameter means?

Comment: It just means that the layout can span the maximum available size compared to others. Say if there are two layouts with android:layout_weight="1" they will share the screen equally. Read more here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: Thanks! Setting the src attribute instead of background made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want exact square shape means you have to set width and height for same value.

If you want to fit all 3 buttons with equal shape in horizontal layout irrespective of screen resolutions, use **layout_weight = 1**. To my knowledge about layouts, only this is the solution.

Comment: But, I cannot set size for the layout. Means, I have them to scale on larger resulutions.

Comment: don't think to scale, weight=1 means it will set size according to screen dimensions. First check the suggestions/answers, then you will get an idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am using weight for layout you can try like this.Set weightsum for linear layout and then set the width of button as 0dp and weight according to your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/answer_bg"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:background="@drawable/img_background"
            android:text="@string/x"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:background="@drawable/img_background"
            android:height="50dip"
            android:text="@string/x"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:background="@drawable/img_background"
            android:text="@string/x"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageButton
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@mipmap/all"></ImageButton>
```

Scale type fitCenter includes full image within button.
3 Image buttons are nested inside horizontal linear layout and each was given weight=1.
Making adjustViewbounds= true, prevented unnecessary stretch of button.